# specific text categorization in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have done a simple text categorization using grepl in R like below:

```
a<-c("treatment | toxic") 
b<-c("other | disease")
check<-c("other treatment", "disease complications","toxic treatment")  


# collapse regular expression
a <- paste(a, collapse = "|")
b <- paste(b, collapse = "|")

count<-length(check)
output<-vector(mode="list",length = count) # Empty categorized list - targeted output is (a,b,a,b)
for (i in 1:count) {
  output[i]<-ifelse(grepl(a,check[i]),"a",ifelse(grepl(b,check[i]),"b","other"))
}

output
```

I managed to get the output except for strings like the first one which has both "other" and "treatment" which in this case will put the string in category a. How can i create something like a priority script where if there is two category keywords in the same string, it will go to category b instead of a and vice versa depending on my selection?

for this example, I would like the output of "other treatment to be in category b". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` which makes it easier to write multiple conditions like this and also allows you to assign priority as per your choice.

```
a<-c("treatment|toxic") 
b<-c("other|disease")
check<-c("other treatment", "disease complications","toxic treatment")  

a_check <- grepl(a, check)
b_check <- grepl(b, check)

#If both a and b matches 
dplyr::case_when(a_check & b_check ~ 'b', 
#If above condition is not satisfied and a matches
                 a_check ~ 'a', 
#If above condition is not satisfied and b matches
                 b_check ~ 'b', 
#If none of the above condition is satisfied
                 TRUE ~ 'none')

#[1] "b" "b" "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to remember with regex is that it is very character sensitive

```
c("treatment ")
```

is a different character match to

```
c("treatment")
```

With that being said, it looks like what you want is a way to choose what happens with a double match. By untangling the complicated nested if, we can easily specify what happens when both conditions match. I've also removed the spaces from the regex expressions, as they will cause the matches to fail.

```
a<-c("treatment|toxic") 
b<-c("other|disease")
check<-c("other treatment", "disease complications","toxic treatment")  


# collapse regular expression
a <- paste(a, collapse = "|")
b <- paste(b, collapse = "|")

count<-length(check)
output<-vector(mode="list",length = count) # Empty categorized list - targeted output is (a,b,a,b)

for (i in 1:count) {

    if (grepl(a,check[i]) & grepl(b,check[i])) {
    #in the case of a double match we are outputting b
    output[i] <- "b"
  } else if (grepl(a,check[i])) {
    output[i] <- "a"
  } else if (grepl(b,check[i])) {
    output[i] <- "b"
  } else {
    output[i] <- "other"
  }
  
}


output
```